# I created multiple dynamic form, but when I submit second form then no value is submitted in DB

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am creating my form in loop.

[forms created by this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXdmC.jpg)

```
function addCmnt(id){

    var name=document.getElementById("cwriter").value;
    var cmnt=document.getElementById("cdata").value;
    var urlFormate="http://localhost:3000/newComment?id="+id;

    $.ajax({
        url: urlFormate,
        type: 'POST',            
        data: {name:name, cmnt:cmnt},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Above code catch the value and send to DB. I works perfect on submission on first form. but it send blank value on second form.

Please suggest me. what can I do?

Comment: did you called that addComment Function inside loop ? you are reloading whole route so it would be clear those form data.